Connect two points on an annulus
I want to prove that the annulus given by the set
$$
B(a;R_1,R_2) =\{{z \in \mathbb{C} : R_1 < |z-a| < R_2\}}
$$
is a connected space. As I am working in $\mathbb{C}$ it is enough to prove it to be arc-connected.
Therefore, given $z_1,z_2 \in B(a;R_1,R_2)$, i have to find a curve $f$ that lies inside the set $B(a;R_1,R_2)$ and passes through both points $z_1 = Re^{i\alpha},z_2=Se^{i\beta}$.
Firstly, I realized that argument should oscillate between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so it should have the form $\alpha (1-t)+t\beta$ for $t \in [0,1]$.
Secondly, I saw that the modulus should oscillate between $R_1$ and $R_2$ so it should have the form $R (1-t)+tS$ for $t \in [0,1]$.
Having that in mind, I came up with the function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
f(t)= (\cos((1-t)\alpha +t\beta) + i \sin((1-t)\alpha +t\beta)) ((1-t)R+tS)
$$
Here, I thought job was done, but the curve $f$ doesn't lay inside the set $B(a;R_1,R_2)$ as it can be seen here

This is a try in Sagemath
R=4
alfa=pi/9
S=2
beta=pi/16
C1 = implicit_plot((x-3)^2 + (y-0)^2==1, (x,0,6), (y,-3,3),color='red')
C2 = implicit_plot((x-3)^2 + (y-0)^2==1, (x,0,6), (y,-3,3),color='red')
P = point((3,0),color='red')
Z1 = point((R*cos(alfa),R*sin(alfa)),color='green')
Z2 = point((S*cos(beta),S*sin(beta)),color='green')
t=var('t')
L = parametric_plot( (cos((1-t)*(alfa)+t*(beta)) * ((1-t)*R+t*S), sin((1-t)*(alfa)+t*(beta)) * ((1-t)*R+t*S))  ,(t,0,1))
C1+C2+P+Z1+Z2+L

I will really appreciate if someone gives me a hint on how  to force the curve $f$ to lay inside the set $B(a;R_1,R_2)$.

Your function looks good, I think you've just graphed it incorrectly. I don't know Sagemath, but it looks like your parametric_plot is only evaluating it at the endpoints.

Looks like you need to say t = var('t') before you call parametric_plot, and then instead of (0,1) at the end, put (t,0,1).

@JonathanZ I think my function is the main issue. I tried your $t=var('t')$ and unfortunately nothing changed. I think I have to center the function plot in the $a$ of $B(a;R_1,R_2)$.

You also have to tell it that your variable is t in the call to parametic_plot. What happens when you also make that second change?

@JonathanZ Thanks, it was a translation mistake. I guess it is necessary to compile, I must have declared it earlier. Thanks for the point.

You're welcome. But as it stands it's not clear if you were able to make it work, and exactly what changes you made to get it to work. If you did, then as a service to others who will read your question, you should add a (short) answer giving the details, and then you can accept your answer so others don't think it's a still-open issue. I hope you did get it to work!

Nope, I'm still open to new ideas. I think I'm missing something.

Your circles are centered at (3,0) (and as written have the same radius, which I assume is just a typo), but you haven't shifted your x-coordinate over by 3 in your parametric plot.

A simple arc could travel from angle $\alpha$ to $\beta$ along the circle of radius $R$, and then from radius $R$ to radius $S$ along the radial at angle $\beta$. If you must parameterize, you could use $t\in[0,\frac12]$ for the circular part and $t\in[\frac12,1]$ for the straight part. But your arc will work of course as long as you measure all angles and distances relative to the center of the annulus, not the origin.

As several users point out the big problem comes when the angles and distances depend on the origin ($0+0i$) instead of your center ($a$). Therefore, it all comes down to calculate the coordinates of $z_1-a$ and $z_2-a$ and replace them in the curve $f$ definition.
Notice that if we don't have the exact values of $z1$ and $a$ we won't have any problem to calculate the modulus, but finding its argument will be an exhaustive task as we cannot use $arg(z) = \arctan (\frac{b}{a})$ because $a=0$ is a problem.
Thus, your curve $f$ looks amazing and cannot admit much improvement, so you can suppose it is centered on the origin as Markus Scheuer states or assuming changes were already made as Morgan Sherman.
Nonetheless, Sagemath has a very useful package called "ComplexDoubleField" that will ease the calculus. From your example we can work as follows:
ComplexDoubleField()
z1 = CDF(R*cos(alfa),R*sin(alfa))
z2 = CDF(S*cos(beta),S*sin(beta))
a = CDF(3,0)
nz1 = CDF(z1-a)
nz2 = CDF(z2-a)

R=4
alfa=pi/9
S=2
beta=pi/16
var('y,t')
C1 = implicit_plot((x-3)^2 + (y-0)^2==3, (x,0,6), (y,-3,3),color='red')
C2 = implicit_plot((x-3)^2 + (y-0)^2==1, (x,0,6), (y,-3,3),color='red')
P = point((3,0),color='red')
Z1 = point((R*cos(alfa),R*sin(alfa)),color='green')
Z2 = point((S*cos(beta),S*sin(beta)),color='green')
L = parametric_plot( (a.real()+cos((1-t)*(nz1.arg())+t*(nz2.arg())) * ((1-t)*(nz1.abs())+t*(nz2.abs())),+\
                  a.imag()+sin((1-t)*(nz1.arg())+t*(nz2.arg())) * ((1-t)*(nz1.abs())+t*(nz2.abs())))  ,(t,0,1))
C1+C2+P+Z1+Z2+L

Observe I just added the real and imaginary part of the center to the curve $f$, and change modulus and argument for the centered ones. With this changes we observe:

Warm regards! If anything is unclear feel free to ask.

$\arctan(a/b)$ is not a problem when $b=0$. But I see that the problem may be to distinguish the argument between the 1st and the 3rd quadrant.

Your annulus is centered at $a \in \mathbb C$ but your definitions thereafter are assuming the center is at the origin.
Instead use
$$ z_1 - a = R e^{i \alpha} \quad \text{and}\quad z_2 - a = S e^{i \beta} $$
and then adjust your function $f$ by adding the real part of $a$ to the $x$-coordinate, and the imaginary part of $a$ to the $y$-coordinate.

We can simplify the settings to ease calculation. We assume wlog that the center of the annulus is at the origin, the absolute value of $z_1=Re^{i\alpha}$ is less or equal the absolute value of $z_2=Se^{i\beta}$. We can rotate the coordinate system, so that $z_1$ is a real number and we assume arguments within $[0,2\pi)$. We consider therefore wlog
\begin{align*}
&a=0\\
&|z_1|\leq |z_2|\\
&\alpha = 0\\
&\beta\in[0,2\pi)
\end{align*}
An arc can now be given as
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\gamma: [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}}\\
&\color{blue}{\gamma(t)=\left((1-t)R+tS\right)e^{i\beta t}}
\end{align*}
with $\gamma(0)=z_1$ and $\gamma(1)=z_2$.
